# How to release everything thats retained by a viewController?

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller, ios6, ipad-3

I have 5 viewControllers which are reloaded each time I tap onto them. I want to reduce the memory allocations so in viewDidDisappear i am making all the IBOutlets nil , but still I want to reduce more memory,which is all that is retained by the controller. Will I have to do it individually or is there any method which will do the magic for me?

Comment: umm... so when the view appears again (viewDidAppear), what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `IBOutlets` to `nil` in `viewDidDisappear` releases nothing as these will all still be retained by the `view`.

You could release your other objects though, and then recreate in `viewDidAppear` but it's hard to understand why you would want to, just do it when asked in the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method.

- Declare your IBOutlets as weak and let the system decide when to release the view (and the outlets along with it) when it needs to.
- Release any other objects you want to drop in low memory conditions inside the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method. Once again the system decides when this is needed.